# Why a dynamic <option> is appended to two dropdown boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have 2 dropdown selection boxes, one is static for terms, the other is static JSON for now but will be dynamic.
I am trying to reflect the proper values into the dropdown box but the regoin/country is appearing in both dropdown boxes?.

The  for my regions is appearing both in terms and regions. 
I have the id tags set but JS is ignoring them and just throwing it to both.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username" value="Mickey">
<br>
domain:<br>
<input type="text" name="domain" value="domain.com">
<br>
term:<br>
        <select name="dexpr">
        <option value="2">2 yr</option>
        <option value="1" selected>1 yr</option>
</select>
<br>
plan:<br>
<input type="text" name="plan" value="">
<br>
servername:<br>
<input type="text" name="servername" value="">
<br>
<br>
<select name = "DCID" id= "DCID">
<option value="None" selected="Selected">Location</option>
</select>
<br>
member id:<br>
<input type="text" name="member_id" value="">
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="provision" value="1">Provision domain?
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
var obj = {
    DCID:[
        {"6":{"DCID":"6","name":"Atlanta","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"GA"},"2":{"DCID":"2","name":"Chicago","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"IL"},"3":{"DCID":"3","name":"Dallas","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"TX"},"5":{"DCID":"5","name":"Los Angeles","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"CA"},"39":{"DCID":"39","name":"Miami","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"FL"},"1":{"DCID":"1","name":"New Jersey","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"NJ"},"4":{"DCID":"4","name":"Seattle","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"WA"},"12":{"DCID":"12","name":"Silicon Valley","country":"US","continent":"North America","state":"CA"},"7":{"DCID":"7","name":"Amsterdam","country":"NL","continent":"Europe","state":""},"25":{"DCID":"25","name":"Tokyo","country":"JP","continent":"Asia","state":""},"8":{"DCID":"8","name":"London","country":"GB","continent":"Europe","state":""},"24":{"DCID":"24","name":"Paris","country":"FR","continent":"Europe","state":""},"9":{"DCID":"9","name":"Frankfurt","country":"DE","continent":"Europe","state":""},"19":{"DCID":"19","name":"Sydney","country":"AU","continent":"Australia","state":""}}
    ]
};

for(var i=0;i<obj.DCID.length;i++){
    var option=$('<option></option>').text(obj.DCID[i]['6']['continent']);
    $('select').append(option);
}
```

LIVE:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2vdrbn5/3/)

How do I properly segregate the 2 list/sets? regions

Comment: `$('select')` matches all the dropdown boxes on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting a *`select`* as a selector.
You should use the selectbox `id` attribute as selector.

Instead of this:

```
$('select').append(option);
```

Use this:

```
$('#DCID').append(option);
```

---

As a side note - if it's possible, you shouldn't modify the DOM inside loop.

```
var options = '';
for(var i=0;i<obj.DCID.length;i++){
    options += '<option value="'+obj.DCID[i]['6']['DCID']+'">' + obj.DCID[i]['6']['continent']+ '</option>';
}
$('#DCID').append(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line:

```
  $('select').append(option);
```

You are telling jquery to find ALL selects in your DOM and append option.

Give the select you want an ID, then use:

```
$('#myRegion').append(option);
```

At this point, jQuery will only append the option to only one select.
I hope that helped